# spring-boot with spring-security integration tests

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a series of Integration Tests that run fine individually, but as a group they fail with primary key violation.

Here are two example tests:

```
class AddressPopulatorTest extends BaseSpecification {

    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository addressRepository

    @Autowired
    private AddressPopulator addressPopulator;

    def "test address list is retrieved from Treasury.gov"() {
        when:
        def count = addressPopulator.populate();

        then:
        def sdnList = addressRepository.findAll()
        sdnList.size() > 5000
        sdnList.size() == count
    }
}
```

and

```
class SdnPopulatorTest extends BaseSpecification {

    @Autowired
    private SdnRepository sdnRepository

    @Autowired
    private SdnPopulator sdnPopulator;


    def "test sdn list is retrieved from Treasury.gov"() {
        when:
        def count = sdnPopulator.populate();

        then:
        def sdnList = sdnRepository.findAll()
        sdnList.size() > 5000
        sdnList.size() == count
    }
```

And here is the base class which I was hoping would initialize everything just once:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyClass, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader)
@Transactional
@IntegrationTest
public class BaseSpecification extends Specification {
}
```

However, each tests appear to be trying to create the database with the schema.sql and populate the security users table with the data.sql file.  I thought the base test class would just do this one time, not for every test.  My schema.sql can check for existing tables and not create if exists

Here is the exception that happens on each test after the first:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_4 ON PUBLIC.USERS(USERNAME)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO users (username, password, enabled) VALUES ('admin', '$2a$10$GVPAMYRozI08Mcll5too6.Q4M2jTO0iJVoiaVDv9pMxRqTpxNj9vO', TRUE) [23505-172]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:83)
    at org.h2.index.TreeIndex.add(TreeIndex.java:65)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:124)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:126)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:86)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:180)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:459)
```

Is there a way to create all database tables with a schema.sql & data.sql inserts once at the beginning of the tests, as I think that seems to be the problem.  Or my approach to this wrong?

Comment: Normal `@ContextConfiguration` with JUnit would work I think (the loader caches the context between test executions). Maybe the Groovy framework (Spock?) that you are using subverts that in some way?

Comment: I am looking at using Flyway as a way to create & populate the database for both production and tests rather than the schema.sql and data.sql.  In the spring-boot-example, it does not show how to configure the jdbc parameters, but I think I just need a flyway.properties file in my resources directory?

Comment: Dave - I don't know if its Spock causing this or not.  Something is odd that for each test the tables are created/populated/destroyed.  However the spring-security tables (user & authorities) seem to still have data in them, causing the primary violation.

Comment: I didn't quite get that last bit, did you mean that the security tables are part if your Flyway migrations or not? (I guess they should be?) How are you running the Flyway migrations (I recommend you use Boot 1.1 native support)?

Comment: Dave - Sorry, I messed up that comment.  I am looking to use Flyway or Liquibase to create and seed my db tables because I can't figure out why the security tables are not being emptied after each test.  I started work on Flyway, but I could not get it to create a dataSource because of missing URL.  I added "flyway.url" to both resources/application.properties and resources/flyway.properties but it wasn't picked up either time.

Comment: I do t think we're going to make any progress until you share your code (or something minimal but complete).

Comment: Thank you Dave,  I wasn't able to get the Flyway working because I didn't know how to get Spring-Boot to pickup the flyway properties.  However, I did manage to get Liquibase startup to load.  So I am going to try and use Liquibase to create and seed my database.